# VB6.Format needing to format a string

Tags: string-formatting, tostring, vb6-migration

I am currently using VB6.Format to format a string such as 2 to 2.000 or from 100.000, but I have been looking on here at examples and haven't been able to figure out how to use the ToString or String.Format to get this working correctly. It needs to be able to take in any number and put three digits after the decimal places such as having 2.2 = 2.200

Thanks for the help in advanced! It needs to be done with the ToString or String.Format.

Answer (score 0):

Use "N3" as in:

X.ToString("N3")

Here are Microsoft's pages on it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use `String.Format("{0:F3}", yourvalue)`